# How can I make a regex character class obligatory?

Tags: php, regex, string

I'm trying to create a pattern. I have images and I want to select these images that contain the string "thumb" and I have the following pseudo structure:

```
something-$s[One of these digits: 1 or 2]thumb.jpg
```

I tried the following regex pattern:

```
$pattern_thumb = "/^.*-$s?[1-2]?\-thumb.jpg$/";
```

It selects these images correctly(`$s = 18054`):

```
imagename-180541-thumb.jpg
imagename-180542-thumb.jpg
```

But the problem is, that it also selects images which don't have a 1 or 2 after the `$s`:

```
imagename-18054-thumb.jpg
```

How to add these digits [1-2] to be obligatory and not optional?

Comment: Remove the `?` after `[1-2]`?

Comment: Thanks you, it's showing correct images now! :)

Comment: @mistery_girl If you put your regex into https://regex101.com you will see, that the `?` makes the character class optional :) Also `[12]` would be the same as it has to pick one of the two characters

Comment: Something like these brackets () .

Comment: @Doorknob冰 I think you can write an answer here, so we can get this question solved? (Note for the answer: `[1-2]` would be the same as `[12]` no range needed ; `\-` does not need to be escaped, since it has no special meaning)

Comment: fyi: http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting for the formatting :P `\`\`\`` -> GitHub `\`` -> SO

Comment: I'll see it, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this pattern: `/^.*-$s[12]\-thumb.jpg$/`

1. You only need 1 and 2 so there is no need to use range: `[1-2]` just 
   `[12]`
2. You need `[12]` be there as mandatory string, so you shouldn't use `?`.

Check [my regex 101 example](https://regex101.com/r/zJ1vY1/1) and [Repetition (PCRE regex syntax; PHP Manual)](http://php.net/manual/regexp.reference.repetition.php).

Comment: Maybe you want to explain what exactly you changed here? And also why you now use `[12]` and not `[1-2]`

Comment: But why if I use it like that: `$pattern_thumb = "/^.*-$s[12]\-thumb.jpg$/";` images are not shown. But if I use it like that: `$pattern_thumb = "/^.*-$s?[12]\-thumb.jpg$/";` - they display.